# Rails autofocus in text field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `text field tag` and I want to turn on the `autofocus` on it.

It works fine without the `id:"email`, but when I add the `id:"email`the `autofocus` does not work.

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], autofocus: true, class: "email", id:"email", placeholder: "#{I18n.t 'email_placeholder'}"%>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with this?

Also, I'm using `typeahead` in this field:

```
<script>
var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/items/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH',
        wildcard: '%SEARCH'
    }
});
$('#email')
    .typeahead(null, {source: items})
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
        e.target.form.submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI you don't need to use string interpolation to provide the placeholder. `I18n.t 'email_placeholder'"` returns a string already, so there is no reason to wrap it in a string. And even if, using `variable.to_s` is preferred over `"#{variable}"`...

Comment: Maybe it is related to the browser? I have checked this and it works perfectly fine in Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (with and without `id`).  
Btw. isn't `id` set automatically to `email`?

Comment: hmmm you gave me an idea @mrShemek, I deleted the email id and used the one that come up by default.. but the autofocus doesn't  work. I failed to mention that I'm using `typeahead` for this field. Maybe there is something wrong with that.

Comment: Well, then try to remove typeahead (the whole `<script>`) and check if autofocus works. If it works, it means that there is something related to the js code, not Rails.